# How to make a dynamic module a global module?

Tags: nestjs

In my application, I want to use a single instance of service class throughout my project. The service class will be initialized by a dynamic module.

**Things in detail**

I have module called LoggerModule which has a static function register. We use this method to initialize in the app module Eg:LoggerModule.register(options). In the register method, we will be returning a dynamic module which will set this options as a custom provider. 
Eg:

```
return {
      module: LoggerModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CONFIG_OPTIONS,
          useValue: options,
        },
        LoggerService,
      ],
      exports: [LoggerService],
    };
```

Here we have a LoggerService that injects the CONFIG_OPTIONS, so that we can fetch options using the service class. Now I want to be able to access the service from anywhere in the project by injecting it in my class, but since the module is not global, currently I will have to include LoggerModule.register() in all the modules that I am using. I tried using the @Global() annotation, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can you suggest any methods on how to do this? If yes please share with me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you should need to do to make a dynamic module global is add the `@Global()` decorator above the `@Module()` decorator. Same with any other module you are working with. [Here are the docs on it](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#global-modules)

---

## Edit 11/22/19

Okay, I tried to mimic your setup as close as I could with what was given and what I still had lying around my local machine. I was able to get a global module working with the following setup:

### Config Module (what will be the global module)

```js
import { DynamicModule, Module, Provider, Global } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CONFIG_MODULE_OPTIONS } from './config.constants';
import { createConfigProvider } from './config.provider';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
import {
  ConfigModuleAsyncOptions,
  ConfigModuleOptions,
  ConfigOptionsFactory,
} from './interfaces/config-options.interface';

@Global()
@Module({})
export class ConfigModule {
  static forRoot(options: ConfigModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: ConfigModule,
      providers: [ConfigService, ...createConfigProvider(options)],
      exports: [ConfigService],
    };
  }

  static forRootAsync(options: ConfigModuleAsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: ConfigModule,
      imports: options.imports || [],
      providers: [ConfigService, ...this.createAsyncProviders(options)],
      exports: [ConfigService],
    };
  }

  private static createAsyncProviders(
    options: ConfigModuleAsyncOptions,
  ): Provider[] {
    if (options.useExisting || options.useFactory) {
      return [this.createAsyncOptionsProviders(options)];
    }
    if (options.useClass) {
      return [
        this.createAsyncOptionsProviders(options),
        {
          provide: options.useClass,
          useClass: options.useClass,
        },
      ];
    }
    throw new Error('Invalid ConfigModule configuration.');
  }

  private static createAsyncOptionsProviders(
    options: ConfigModuleAsyncOptions,
  ): Provider {
    if (options.useFactory) {
      return {
        provide: CONFIG_MODULE_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: options.useFactory,
        inject: options.inject || [],
      };
    }
    return {
      provide: CONFIG_MODULE_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: async (optionsFactory: ConfigOptionsFactory) =>
        await optionsFactory.createConfigOptions(),
      inject: [options.useExisting || options.useClass || ''],
    };
  }
}
```

I had this set up for a completely reusable Nest Module but scrapped the idea as there are already a few config modules out there, hence all the boilerplate.

### Dyanmic Module (yes I know it's spelled wrong)

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DyanmicTestService } from './dyanmic-test.service';
import { DyanmicTestController } from './dyanmic-test.controller';

@Module({
  providers: [DyanmicTestService],
  controllers: [DyanmicTestController],
})
export class DyanmicTestModule {}
```

The Dyanmic Service injects the Config Service, but notice we don't import the Config Module here. That's because it is global, and once registered in the App Module, it doesn't need to be imported anywhere else.

### App Module

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { DyanmicTestModule } from './dyanmic-test/dyanmic-test.module';
import { ConfigModule } from './config/config.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        fileName: '.env',
        useProcess: false,
      }),
    }),
    DyanmicTestModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

All of this code [can also be found on my GitHub](https://github.com/jmcdo29/dynamic-module-test/tree/global-module).

Comment: Yes, I did try that and I couldn't make it work. Do you have a working example of it? Thanks.

Comment: What about it didn't work? I've got some old code lying around somewhere with it. Could you possibly show a little bit more about the module you are seeing to global and a module/service that is consuming the service you are trying to work with?

Comment: Thanks for yout answer. I understood the mistake that I did, I had intialized the module in wrong order which caused the issue. Thanks for your help